# How create a database organized by tags

Tags: mysql, database, tags

I would create a database whose contents are organized by tags.

I created two tables, one called "games" and other "platforms", and created a column called "plataforma_id" in table "games" to be able to call a specific platform, but some games have more than one platform, so I would know how to do call two or more platforms in my "games" table.

Ex:

TABLE GAMES

id | platform_id | name

1  | 1           | game1

2  | 2           | game1

*I want call more than one platform for game1

TABLE PLATFORMS

id | name

1  | PC

2  | Mac

3  | Linux

Comment: I suggest a third table for relationships between GAMES and PLATFORMS. The table might only contain `game_id` and `platform_id`. Each game/platform pair will exist as a row in that table. You might also want to set a unique index on the two columns so that each pairing is unique, and handle duplicate inserts with [ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: I just noticed your table columns. Are there really columns in GAMES called `1`, `game 1 2`, and `2`? What's the difference between `GAMES.name 1` and `GAMES.game1`? What's the purpose of `PLATFORMS.PC 2`, `PLATFORMS.Mac 3`, and `PLATFORMS.Linux`? Wouldn't those values go into `PLATFORMS.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Florent is correct, you'll need "many-to-many" relationships, via a third table. Any number of games can match any number of platforms. Use JOINs to link the three tables together with the appropriate relationships.

However, I have a different idea for your schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `platforms` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `games` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `games_platforms` (
  `game_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `platform_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique pair` (`game_id`,`platform_id`)
);
```

Given the following data:

```
INSERT INTO `platforms` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Platform 1'),
(2, 'Platform 2'),
(3, 'Platform 3');

INSERT INTO `games` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Game 1'),
(2, 'Game 2'),
(3, 'Game 3');

INSERT INTO `games_platforms` (`game_id`, `platform_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1);
```

And the following query:

```
SELECT g.`name` as `game_name`, p.`name` as `platform_name`
FROM `games` g
LEFT JOIN `games_platforms` gp ON (gp.`game_id`=g.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `platforms` p ON (p.`id`=gp.`platform_id`);
```

We get the following results:

```
GAME_NAME   PLATFORM_NAME
---------   -------------
Game 1      Platform 1
Game 1      Platform 2
Game 2      Platform 1
Game 3      (null)
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2445d/1/0)

---

## DISPLAYING AS HTML:

In order to output the data to HTML, execute your database query in whichever server-side language you are using (I'm using PHP in these examples) and generate the appropriate HTML. Choose an HTML layout of your choice to display the data (I'm using tables).

### SQL Processing:

For smaller data sets, you can perform some processing in your database query itself. For example, you can [concatenate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) data for display:

```sql
// fetch platforms by game

$sql="SELECT
    g.`name` as `game_name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        COALESCE(p.`name`, 'n/a') ORDER BY p.`name` ASC SEPARATOR ', '
    ) as `platform_names`,
    COUNT(p.`id`) as `platform_count`
FROM `games` g
LEFT JOIN `games_platforms` gp ON (gp.`game_id`=g.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `platforms` p ON (p.`id`=gp.`platform_id`)
GROUP BY g.`id`
ORDER BY g.`name` ASC;";
```

I created [a few examples of database queries HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0afcf1/10).

Then output your resulting dataset in PHP:

```php
...

// list platforms by game

?><table border="1">
    <thead><tr><th>Game</th><th>Platforms</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><?php

    while ($row=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        ?><tr>
            <td><?=$row['game_name']?></td>
            <td><?=$row['platform_names']?></td>
            <td><?=$row['platform_count']?></td>
        </tr><?php

    }

    ?></tbody>
</table><?php

...
```

Which looks something like this:

```
Game        Platforms                             Platform Count
----        ---------                             --------------
Game 1      Platform 1, Platform 2, Platform 5    3
Game 2      Platform 1, Platform 3                2
Game 3      Platform 1, Platform 2, Platform 5    3
Game 4      Platform 2                            1
Game 5      n/a                                   0
Game 6      Platform 1, Platform 5                2
```

Here's a [**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://phpad.org/1983308812) of that.

### PHP Processing:

It might be too time consuming to preform queries like that on large datasets. Or, you might need to process results more rigorously than is practical within the database query itself. If this is the case, you might want to do the processing with PHP rather than with the database queries themselves.

Start by performing a more general query like this:

```php
// fetch platforms by game

$sql="SELECT g.`id` as `game_id`, g.`name` as `game_name`,
      p.`id` as `platform_id`, p.`name` as `platform_name`
FROM `games` g
LEFT JOIN `games_platforms` gp ON (gp.`game_id`=g.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `platforms` p ON (p.`id`=gp.`platform_id`);";
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0afcf1/11)

Then process the result into an array:

```
while ($row=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    // add this row's game to the array
    $entries[$row['game_id']]['game']=array(
        'id'=>$row['game_id'],
        'name'=>$row['game_name']
    );

    // if there's a platform for this row, add it to the game entry
    if ($row['platform_id']) {
        $entries[$row['game_id']]['platforms'][]=array(
            'id'=>$row['platform_id'],
            'name'=>$row['platform_name']
        );
    }

}
```

Then output that array into a table
(indentation flattened a bit to save space):

```
?><table border="1">
<thead><tr><th>Game</th><th>Platforms</th><th>Platform Count</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><?php

foreach ($entries as $entry) {

    ?><tr>
    <td><a href="#view_game.php?id=<?=$entry['game']['id']?>"><?=$entry['game']['name']?></a></td>
    <td><?php

    if (empty($entry['platforms'])) {
        echo "n/a";
    } else {
        foreach ($entry['platforms'] as $platform) {
            ?><p><a href="#view_platform.php?id=<?=$platform['id']?>"><?=$platform['name']?></a></p><?php
        }
    }

    ?></td>
    <td><?=!empty($entry['platforms'])?count($entry['platforms']):0?></td>
    </tr><?php

}

?></tbody>
</table><?php
```

With that, you can generate a potentially more robust table of data, *complete with potential links* to games and platforms and other features. Something like this:

```
Game        Platforms      Platform Count
----        ---------      --------------
Game 1      Platform 1     3
            Platform 2
            Platform 5

Game 2      Platform 1     2
            Platform 3

Game 3      Platform 1     3
            Platform 4
            Platform 5

Game 4      Platform 2     1

Game 5      n/a            0

Game 6      Platform 1     2
            Platform 5
```

Here's a [**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://phpad.org/2020678116) of that.

These are just some ideas and brainstorms of what you can do with your dataset. Databases allow for some really interesting manipulation of data and the possibilities seem endless.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much !!! :D
Taking advantage, you could help me with the print of this data in PHP? Because I do not know how to print only name of the game + all its platforms.

ex:
I want to print:

Game: game1
Platforms: platform1, platform2, platform3

Comment: Again! Many thanks! You help me so much. Now I can create a awesome app.

Comment: my apologies for once again requesting your help, but I would like the query to display all platforms more all genres (example) following the same principles.

I created two tables for genres following the same principles of the platforms tables, so I create a table "genre" and "games_genres" exactly how the platforms tables, but do not know how to make the SQL query display all genres and all platforms for a specific game.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a many-to-many relation between A and B. This is done with a 3rd table A_B with ID column from A and B

TABLE GAMES

id | name 1 | 1 | game1 2 | 2 | game1

TABLE PLATFORMS

id | name 1 | PC 2 | Mac 3 | Linux

TABLE GAMES_PLATFORMS

id_game | id_platform

You will need to use `JOIN`for your `select` queries